# Как уменьшить картинку на go приведя её к определённой ширине и высоте?

Tags: golang, изображения

Нужно взять файл картинки большого размера и создать её уменьшенную копию с определённой высотой и шириной.
Как такое сделать?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Я бы брал imagemagick - есть биндинг к го https://github.com/gographics/imagick . А дальше - чтение документации и изучение примера - https://github.com/gographics/imagick/blob/master/examples/resize/main.go

А вот какую ширину и высоту задать - это уже Вам решать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот библиотека без биндингов: https://github.com/nfnt/resize

Простой пример использования:

```
package main

import (
    "image/jpeg"
    "os"
    "github.com/nfnt/resize"
)

func main(){
    imgIn, _ := os.Open("test.jpg")
    imgJpg, _ := jpeg.Decode(imgIn)
    imgIn.Close()

    imgJpg = resize.Resize(600, 0, imgJpg, resize.Bicubic) // <-- Собственно изменение размера картинки

    imgOut, _ := os.Create("test-out.jpg")
    jpeg.Encode(imgOut, imgJpg,nil)
    imgOut.Close()
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/108539)

Comment: Это ссылка на библиотеку для ресайза изображений, собственно она и является главным. Если страница перестанет существовать - то перестанет существовать и библиотека и ответ станет неактуальным. Нужно будет найти другую библитеку.

Comment: Развернутый, качественный ответ. Эту цель преследует SO. То что находится по ссылке, является правильным ответом, я и не сомневаюсь) Можно описать библиотеку, почему она, лучшие/худшие её качества. Что-то в этом роде :)

Comment: Спасибо @rekby . https://github.com/nfnt/resize больше понравился ,т.к. imagick не смог установить- он походу на Си написан и кучу пакетов требовал, и так и не смог поставить на винду

Comment: Здравствуйте Роман. Тогда отметьте ответ как ответ - зеленой галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Существует пакет [golang.org/x/image/draw](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/image/draw), позволяющий это сделать.

При изменении размера изображения происходит искажение и потеря данных. Для достижения необходимого эффекта используется тот или иной способ [интерполяции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Одни способы дают хорошую производительность - другие качество. В вышеупомянутом пакете встроено четыре метода интерполяции:

- [*NearestNeighbor*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0) - интерполяция методом ближайшего соседа. Самый простой и быстрый алгоритм. Однако обычно результат низкого качества. При увеличении, результат становится "квадратным"
- *ApproxBiLinear* - это смесь между NearestNeighbor и BiLinear. Он быстр, но обычно даёт результат среднего качества
- [*BiLinear*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) медленная, но даёт хороший результат
- *CatmullRom* использует сплайн Катмулл-Рома (англ. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline)). Очень медленный, но даёт очень хороший результат

Пример для преобразования по методу CatmullRom

```java
import (
    "image"

    "golang.org/x/image/draw"
)

func main() {
    // открытие изображения источника
    // любым угодным способом
    src := openImage()
    // создаём пустое изображение для
    // записи необходимого размера
    dst := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 200, 200))
    // изменение размера
    draw.CatmullRom.Scale(dst, dst.Bounds(),
        src, src.Bounds(),
        draw.Over, nil)
    // готово

    // теперь dst содержит итоговое изображение

}
```

Иображение для примера[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Результат для различных способов интерполяции при уменьшении в два раза

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На двухядерном Intel Core i3 M380 2.53GHz результат уменьшения вдвое по времени:

```
|      метод      |     время     |
|:---------------:|--------------:|
| NearestNeighbor |    7.935489ms |
| ApproxBiLinear  |   14.876478ms |
| BiLinear        |  113.903067ms |
| CatmullRom      |  115.972061ms |
```

Полный пример используемого приложения можно посмотреть на [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/logrusorgru/570d64fd6a051e0441014387b89286ca). Используя этот пример и различные наборы исходных изображений можно, посмотрев результаты, выбрать для своей задачи оптимальный метод интерполяции

---

- [golang.org/x/image/draw](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/image/draw)
- [пример приложения](https://gist.github.com/logrusorgru/570d64fd6a051e0441014387b89286ca)